# Changing the name of layer using python

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, layers

I am attempting to change the name of the layer. The following code changes the name of the layer but then removes the layer from the map, and I am not sure why.

Note: I don't have any remove layer statements.

```
for lyrs in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df):
    if lyrs.name == "project_ws":
        lyrs.name = "project_prow"

arcpy.RefreshTOC()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be doing this in a geoprocessing tool. GP tools try to protect the TOC from manipulation (such as suppressing the outputs of tools called within tools from going to the TOC), so you're going to need to tell it explicitly that you mean to keep this layer around. "But I haven't added a layer!" -- it goes by name, not by reference, so as far as it's concerned `"project_prow"` is some new rogue layer.

Make a new output parameter of type Feature Layer, and use `SetParameterAsText` to set its value to the `lyrs.name`.

Comment: Yes in a geoprocessing tool, ekk forgot to mention that :(

Comment: How could you tell he was doing it in a geoprocessing tool? Because it wasn't working?

Comment: Because of the behavior of how the TOC was being manipulated, yes. The script tool thought the "new" layer was intermediate output after it finished and clobbered it.